# Is there a command for netdisco to reinitialize the database?

Tags: database, postgresql, netdiscover

Is there a command for [netdisco](https://metacpan.org/release/App-Netdisco) to reinitialize the database ?

I know that I could use `truncate table_name` for each table but is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two other solutions that are documented now here: https://github.com/netdisco/netdisco/wiki/Database#reinitialize-database

The first one is to drop the database and recreate it (https://github.com/netdisco/netdisco/wiki/Database#complete-reinitialization):

```
# First stop netdisco
netdisco$ ~/bin/netdisco-web stop
netdisco$ ~/bin/netdisco-daemon stop

# Connect as postgres
netdisco$ sudo su - postgres

# Delete DB
postgres$ dropdb netdisco
# Create DB
postgres$ createdb netdisco

# Disconnect <Ctrl><D>
#Init DB
netdisco$ ~/bin/netdisco-deploy
```

The second one is less convenient, you just delete devices one by one from the netdisco's GUI (https://github.com/netdisco/netdisco/wiki/Database#delete-data-from-the-gui)